# In emacs, how can I add a function to a hook when the function hasn't yet been defined?

Tags: emacs, elisp, elpa

I've installed some things from ELPA, namely evil and rainbow-delimiters.

In order to have them run whenever emacs loads, I would put something like:

```
(evil-mode)
(global-rainbow-delimiters-mode)
```

In my init.el file.

However, because I installed them from ELPA, they're not loaded until after my init.el has been loaded, and so both symbols are undefined.

As far as I understand, this also prevents me from doing something like

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-rainbow-delimiters-mode)
```

How can I work around this?

Postscript: This problem was actually caused by me not calling `(package-initialize)` at the start of my init.el, which would have loaded all of the things installed using packages (evilmode and rainbow-delimiters being just two of them) at the correct time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `add-hook` solution will work.

There, `'global-rainbow-delimiters-mode` is just a name, it will be resolved to the function later, when `add-hook` is called, and the function will exist by that time.

The [ELPA documentation](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA) does mention this method, although it seems to consider it as a last resort.

Comment: So it does. This seems peculiar, I thought I'd tried it, and it didn't work. Perhaps I forgot to byte compile my init file last time

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU compiling the init file is not a good idea - but not related so far.

Your hook fails, as it runs after reading the init, but before stuff gets loaded. You need a function to run after load from ELPA.

Try eval-after-load

Comment: Why is compiling my init.el a bad idea?

Comment: I've compiled init.el for years.  The problem is that if you make changes and forget to compile Emacs will load the old byte-compiled version and you might be confused why it doesn't have your changes.  I have added hooks to startup and shut down that ask if I want to compile init.el (if it has changed), so that I never forget to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also initialize your packages early with `(package-initialize)`. This will allow you to not put all that code in one hook.